# How to show the GMT tiemstamp by moment.js

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I need to get the UTC timestamp by moment.js,I had writen code show as below

const timestamp = moment().utc().unix();
console.log(timestamp);

but it didn't work,it show the local time instead,the document of moment.js also said that it will be created in local mode if I use unix().

if I want to show the UTC time in timestamp without extra function supported,how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Why use moment? Just use the built in date object

```js
let date = new Date();
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Required by ourself,or I can achieve my goal by many methods in JavaScript

Comment: Moment is a fat bloated library that is an outdated style of JavaScript library that can't be tree shaken. Even the authors of the library no longer recommend it's use.

Answer (score 0):

```
//moment.utc();

const utc = moment.utc();
utc.format()
utc.valueOf()
```

Comment: After my testing,utc.format() can show the correct GMT time but not timestamp,and utc.valueOf() can show the correct timestamp of milliseconds but not GMT,will be converted into local time also.

Comment: yeah we can do it with format which is for format the time which we expects